# Mixing bytes and words with DUP in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I use MASM 5.10 on an old DOS machine.

I have the following table in memory:

```
                            ;sprPropTab is the sprite property table.
                            ;It is a table that holds the properties
                            ;of each present sprite.

                            ;NPC sprite properties are initialized
                            ;when the current area is built from data files.

 sprPropTab db 0            ;player is always type 0
            dw 0,0          ;player sprite's current X/Y coord
            dw 0a000h       ;player sprite's flag
            db ?            ;first npc sprite's type
            dw ?,?          ;first npc sprite's X/Y coord
            dw ?            ;first npc sprite's flag
            db ?          
            dw ?,?   
            dw ?  
            db ?          
            dw ?,?   
            dw ?  
            db ?          
            dw ?,?   
            dw ? 
            db ?          
            dw ?,?   
            dw ? 
            db ?          
            dw ?,?   
            dw ? 
            db ?          
            dw ?,?   
            dw ?
```

I want to increase sprPropTab from 8 entries to 32 entries. I would like to be able to define the NPC sprite property portion using DUP (or any other method)
to decrease the number of lines required.

One way to do this would be to define the sprite type as a word, rather than a byte.

```
sprPropTab dw 0                ;player is always type 0
           dw 0,0              ;player sprite's current X/Y coord
           dw 0a000h           ;player sprite's flag
           dw 31 dup (?,?,?,?) ;NPC sprite's properties
```

However, sprite type only ranges from a value of 0 to 32, so I would end up wasting 32 bytes that way. The other way I could do it would be to define the entire table as bytes.

```
NPCSiz     equ 31*7           ;The size of the NPC portion of the 
                              ;sprite property table in bytes.

sprPropTab db  0              ;player is always type 0
           db  0,0,0,0        ;player sprite's current X/Y coord
           db  0,0a0h         ;player sprite's flag
           db  NPCSiz dup (?) ;NPC sprite's properties
```

The problem with that is I would then need to add an extra XCHG instruction every time I want to access a sprite's flag word, X coordinate, or Y coordinate. (Or write more complicated code to initialize the words with little endianness in mind.)

Is there syntax to define the table using DUP without altering the size of it's elements?

Comment: It's just memory. The way you *reserve* it doesn't define how you *access* it. You can access it as bytes, words, whatever you like. So just reserve 31*5 bytes and go for it.

Comment: You can use structs or records if you need a more high-level approach. Personally, I find it very boilerplate. What I like to do is define a flat buffer and then define macros/functions that, given an index, get/set a property. If you do this into a separate file (segments are grouped) you can even achieve poor-man "encapsulation" :)

Comment: I'd recommend reordering your data so that all the elements have natural alignment.  (i.e. use `db` in pairs to all the `dw` elements have 2-byte alignment, assuming the start of the region is aligned by 8 or 16 or something).  This way a 2-byte access can never be split across a cache-line or page boundary (performance problem).  You can also group things so related things are nearby and can maybe be loaded / copied with a 4-byte load or 8 / 16-byte SSE2 load.

Comment: And you don't want to have the sprite size an odd value, so pad that to align to something divisible by 2, 4 or even 8. With your current size 5 I would pad it to 8, ... and then reserve just 31*8 memory after the first defined entry. That makes also code like `mov al,[sprPropTab + xcoordoffset + esi*8]` valid to access i-th sprite with `esi = i` ... in 32b mode. (in x86-16 you are of course very limited with valid memory operands, not having any scaling ones, still calculating *8 is simple `shl si,3`, better than `*5`).

Comment: @ped7g I am constained to 16 bit only code. And i'm using simple index + displacement addressing to access the table. `mov ax, WORD PTR [bx+1]` I just alter bx between accesses to navigate the table. (add 7 to it to move through entries)

Comment: You can use `EQU` for the displacements to give them some name, like `SPRITE_COORD_X EQU 1`. And padding to size 8 will make your multiply to be just `shl` instead of slow `mul`. And in DOS you are not constrained to 16b only, you can use some 32b extender like DOS4GW to use protected mode, but that's not like simple switch, would take several days of studying and experimenting + rewriting all the code... but for new medium/large project definitely the only choice, 16b is so much pain due to those limits. Last time I did larger project for DOS, I used Watcom C with TASM (+ 32b mode of course).

Comment: I've constrained myself to 16 bit code. When I use displacements, I explain what they point to in the comments. No need to name the displacements. Also, I'm limiting line length (including comments) to 78 columns to make it easier to read code in DOS editors. I've come up with a solution to my problem. I'm just going to use 5 unused bits in the Flag word to describe the sprite type (0-31), and get rid of the sprite type byte all together.

Comment: The named displacement allow you for simpler modification of structure in future. Now if you removed the 1 byte in middle, you will have to adjust all +3 to +2 in the code. If you would use named displacement, you would fix only the +3 equ, and total size equ. 78 column limit will make this a bit harder, but displacement equs should probably fit well, you will save on comments. (I'm generally strongly against macros/hiding implementation stuff in asm, but named displacements are OK with me). - anyway, these are just advices, feel free to follow your own path :) I'm just mildly disapproving...